# Setting an NHibernate COMB Generated ID

Tags: nhibernate

What are the implications of setting the ID property of a new entity to Guid.NewGuid when the generator for that ID is set to guid.comb?  Will NHibernate overwrite the supplied ID with a new ID when it is saved?  Or will it keep the ID I set on the entity?

Comment: What results have you observed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be replaced by the one from guid.comb.

Comment: Yep after experimenting it looks like the ID that we set on the entity gets overwritten by the generated one.